# Toubleshooting PCB circuit - strange Zener diode behaviour

Tags: resistance, zener, repair, troubleshooting, tolerance

I have two units of a device which I shall call deviceA and deviceB. DeviceB is malfunctioning.

Therefore I compared the resistance values of the same components on the boards of both deviceA and deviceB in order to find the one(s) which have failed. I know this is not the best way to proceed, but being deviceA and deviceB identical, it think it is an acceptable strategy.

I noticed that several components do not share its value with the corresponding component on the other board; I am talking of a 5% to 50% difference.

Then a 8.2v Zener diode, on deviceA it has a 15K ohm resistance, on deviceB its resistance is a some 20 ohm. Therefore I decided to swap the two components in order to check if it was the cause of the defect.

I found now that the swapped components are working the same as before, ie. the 8.2v Zener diode on deviceA it has a 15K ohm resistance, on deviceB its resistance is a some 20 ohm.

Therefore I have to assume there must be some other component on the board which is inducing deviceB strange behaviour.

How would I go on troubleshooting malfunctioning deviceB?

Please let me know thanks.

Comment: Look for any other components that are connected in parallel with the zener. Likely candidates are electrolytic or tantalum capacitors or chips (assuming the zener is connected to a power rail used by chips). If you have a schematic, it would help to post it.

Comment: @ThePhoton Ok, I will check and let you know, probably tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: The resistance you measure across a Zener diode will vary, depending on the polarity.  It will likely be quite low when the anode is positive (diode forward biased), and much higher when the cathode is positive.

Comment: @ThePhoton Your suggestion did the trick. If you are willing to turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it as a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely the fault is in some other component connected in parallel with the zener. Likely candidates are electrolytic or tantalum capacitors or chips (assuming the zener is connected to a power rail used by chips).